# Custom dimensions/metrics in Google Analytics

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, custom-controls, google-analytics-api

I set up the below code 3 days ago.  I want to set up a custom variable to use in `Google Analytics`.  After 3 days I still do not see the variables `percentage` or `score` in my GA account (unless I just don't know where to look but I think I have looked in every available area).

I see all my page views in GA just not these custom variables.

Is this or is this not the way to set up custom variables in GA?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.results);

    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);
    final Tracker tracker = EasyTracker.getTracker();       

    cAnswers = getIntent().getIntExtra("correctAnswers", -1);
    wAnswers = getIntent().getIntExtra("wrongAnswers", -1);
    score = getIntent().getLongExtra("score", -1);
    category = getIntent().getStringExtra("category");
    qs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("queries");

    percentage = 10 * cAnswers;

    tracker.setCustomMetric(1, (long)percentage);
    tracker.setCustomMetric(2, score);
    tracker.sendView();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code matches [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/customdimsmets#custom-metrics) for creating custom metrics. Have you checked manually that `(long)percentage` and `score` are returning an appropriate type?

**Edit**
If your code is running fine (and it seems like it should be), the custom metrics will be available through the API, custom reports, and advanced segments ([docs here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/features/customdimsmets#reporting)), but they won't show up in any default reports automatically.

It sounds like you're interested in seeing the metrics through the web interface, so here's some info on [creating custom reports](http://www.google.com/analytics/features/custom-reports.html).

Comment: Yes, there are returning an appropriate type.  Is there something in google.com/analytics that I have to do first?  Or is it just like a ````Pageview```` where it just shows up on its own?

Comment: Got it. I think your code may be working fine, but you won't see custom metrics and dimensions show up automatically. I'll update my answer with more info on how to view them.